# Wordpress meta.php Fatal error: allowed memory size

Tags: php, wordpress, out-of-memory, meta

I have a prompt function that every night sync a huge quatity of datas for statistics use.
This function query 3k posts at time, until get_posts don't have more posts.
After 8 iterations, i have this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /path/to/file
```

This is the function:

```
public static function sync_orders() {
    $pagination = 0;
    $post_orders = self::get_posts($pagination); //retrieve 3k posts
    while ($post_orders) {
        /** @var WP_Post $order */
        foreach ($post_orders as $order) {
            //some actions
        }
        $pagination++;
        echo "Pagination $pagination \n";
        wp_cache_flush();
        $post_orders = null;
        $post_orders = self::get_posts($pagination);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP

Comment: @Danijel I know that I can increase the memory limit, but my question is: why memory increases if, at the end of each cycle, I reuse the same variables?